# Which mongoose query fails using async await

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

I have a small requirement.
I am trying to add documents into 2 different collections as shown below. In the below code, **Test1_Model** and **Test2_Model** are Mongoose Models in Node.js.

```
try {
  const test1 = new Test1_Model({ name: "Dummy" });
  const saveTest1 = await test1.save();
  const test2 = new Test2_Model({ field: "Something" })
  const saveTest2 = await test2.save();
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Now the requirement is to know that which of the above mongoose query returned an error and which one completed successfully. Yes, if **test1.save()** fails then test2.save() will not execute only but there can be a situation that **test1.save()** completes but test2.save() fails. So the aim is to know that exactly which of the query failed.

The above problem can be solved by replacing async/await into Promise handling using **.then()** and **.catch()**. You can find that solution below.

```
try {
  const test1 = new Test1_Model({ name: "Dummy" });
  const saveTest1 = test1.save().then().catch(err => {
    throw new Error('Test1 Failed');
  });
  const test2 = new Test2_Model({ field: "Something" })
  const saveTest2 = test2.save().then().catch(err => {
    throw new Error('Test2 Failed');
  });
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

This solves the problem but the aim is to know that by using async/await, can we do something like this.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you will need Promise.allSetteled. [The Promise.allSettled() method returns a promise that resolves after all of the given promises have either fulfilled or rejected, with an array of objects that each describes the outcome of each promise.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a wrapper for every promise and throw an error or pass data from it.

```
const promiseHandler = (promise) => {
  return promise
    .then(data => ([data, undefined]))
    .catch(error => Promise.resolve([undefined, error]));
}
try {
  const test1 = new Test1_Model({ name: "Dummy" });
  const [saveTest1, error] = await handle(test1.save());
  if (error) throw new Error(`Error is on saveTest ${error}`)
  const test2 = new Test2_Model({ field: "Something" })
  const [saveTest2, error] = await handle(test2.save());
  if (error) throw new Error(`Error is on saveTest2 ${error}`)
} catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
}
```

Comment: This works for me but still my expectation is to know that the error object which is available in catch block, does that object contains some information about the failing query. Can we use that object itself to know which one is failing.

Comment: In simple terms, no, it is not verbose that can help you to indentify which promise is failing. However you can make the wrapper more robust to identify the type of data promise you are referring to and  create an error object with more information. If the answer is working fine, you can accept and upvote it for future reference. thanks.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help Apoorva :)